# Web Page Blocked!の原因特定と回避策について

Tags: network

CX-Checkerという静的解析ツールを使いたいのですが公式ページ（ http://www.sapid.org/cxc/ ）にブラウザからアクセスすると下記のメッセージがでて接続できません。

---

Web Page Blocked!
You have tried to access a web page which belongs to a category that is blocked.

---

検索したところ、DNSフィルタによってブロックされている可能性があるとのことで、DNS指定をGoogleのPublicDNSに切り替えてみたのですが、現象は変わらずでした。

ブラウザはEdge、Chrome、Firefoxで試しましたが、いずれも同じメッセージが表示されて接続できません。

このメッセージは誰がどういう理由で出していて、このメッセージを回避して正常にサイトにアクセスする方法がわかりません。

切り分け方法についてご教示いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

オイラんところの社内ネットからも、個人のスマホからも同一画面になったし、開発者ツールで HTML ソースやデバッグ Console を見た限りにおいて、

> `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)`
> `www.sapid.org/:1`

となっているので `sapid.org` のバックエンドが停止しているのだと思われます。ンで、フロントエンドつまり httpd 自体は

> `<title>Fortinet Secure DNS Service Portal</title>`

となっているので Fortinet が提供している様子ですが、バックエンドが停止してることをセキュリティエラー（誰かが攻撃した結果として `sapid.org` のバックエンドが停止している）と誤って判断してこのメッセージになっているものと思われます。

結論：オイラたち読者ができることは何もありません。復旧を待ってください。
(そもそも `sapid.org` がまだ生きている＝サービス停止してないあたりの検証から必要になるかもしれない：バックエンドが停止している＝もうサービス停止してるとしたら絶望）